# Genotype of siblings given identity by descent status

Tags: probability, biology

I have a question regarding genotype of siblings (specifically I am referring to the table on slide 19 here:
http://ibgwww.colorado.edu/workshop2005/cdrom/ScriptsA/evans/IBDestimation/IBD--2005.pdf  )

> Say the prevalence of an allele, say $A_1$, is $p_1$ and the prevalence of allele $A_2$ is $p_2$ in the population. Is there anyway we can determine the conditional probability of the observed genotype of two siblings given the identity by descent (IBD) status (i.e. $P(\text{sibling }1=A_1A_1, \text{sibling }2=A_1A_1) = ?$, $P(\text{sibling }1=A_1A_2, \text{sibling }2= A_2A_2)=?)$?

I am asking the question because I am not sure how the author determines the probability in the table based on just knowing the IBD of the two siblings.

Can someone explain column of probability when $k=1$?  I don't really understand how one can get for example $p_1$ to the $2$ times $p_2$ in the table when $k=1$ when the sibling genotype are sibling $1=A_1A_1$ and sibling $2=A_1A_2$.

Comment: Your question should be self-contained. Therefore your last question will likely not be answered; few people are going to search through that pdf to figure out what you are talking about. You can write tables in the question itself, see this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5044/259085

Comment: I thought it would be better if I give more details by providing a link? because if I just type out the table and people with no genetic background might not know what I am asking.

Comment: On the other hand, people with no genetic background probably won't spend time reading up on it. Therefore your question should contain all information that is relevant to the math part of it, and not much else; you should of course explain what the entries in the table means, but preferably in terms of math (probability and the like) and not in terms of genetics. Very basic genetics concepts are okay to include, since it will help to convey what you want to figure out, even though you may not be able to formulate it mathematically. But keep the audience in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you understand the columns $k=0$ and $k=2$, which correspond to the siblings having no identity by descent and complete identity by descent, respectively.

For $k=1$, the siblings share one allele. Thus there are three alleles in play, the one they share and the ones they each have that they don't share, and these three alleles are modelled as independent.

To get genotypes $A_1A_1$ and $A_1A_2$, the shared allele must be $A_1$ and the other two must be $A_1$ and $A_2$. The probability for three alleles to be $A_1$, $A_1$, $A_2$ is $p_1^2p_2$.

The more interesting case is where both genotypes are $A_1A_2$, since in this case both alleles could be the shared one. We can calculate this as the complement of the remaining probabilities, which are easier to determine:

$$1-\left(p_1^3+2p_1^2p_2+2p_1p_2^2+p_2^3\right)=1-(p_1+p_2)^3+p_1^2p_2+p_2^2p_1=p_1p_2(p_1+p_2)=p_1p_2\;.$$

Or we can add the two cases: The probability for the shared allele to be $A_2$ and the other two to be $A_1$ is $p_1^2p_2$, and the probability for the shared allele to be $A_1$ and the other two to be $A_2$ is $p_1p_2^2$, for a total of $p_1^2p_2+p_1p_2^2=p_1p_2(p_1+p_2)=p_1p_2$.